# What hardware could I use for a rotating / swivel tv cabinet?

Tags: flange

We're wanting to mount a TV under our covered patio. Hot tub is on the other side, so I'd like to build something like this:

[image]

This would let me leave the TV protected (by facing it under the patio), but we could spin it for viewing in the hot tub.

I'm having trouble figuring out what hardware to use for the rotation. This flange bearing seems close, but the bolt goes through the center so there's no space for a power cable:

[image]

This pipe flange seems perfect but I can't figure out what bearing to use with it. Seems like hanging it by the threads and using those for rotation is not a good plan:

[image]

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure that you put in stops so that the TV can only rotate 180°, then back (i.e. clockwise to open, counter-clockwise to close, or vice-versa). Otherwise, you'll end up twisting all your cables until they break because people will naturally want to push on one side to both open and close.

Comment: Do the cables have to go through the center?

Comment: @user253751 ideally, yeah - cables through the center

Comment: This is what you need: http://www.mcmaster-carr.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Floor flanges like you show top and bottom would actually work beautifully. Use a little lithium grease to keep things from seizing up and be happy with a robust, cheap solution. You could put a pair of cross tees on the mast with protruding nipples for mounting. 1" or 1¼" pipe would look good and could contain power and HDMI cables.

To create a swivel stop you could notch the end of the pipe and put a set screw through the flange.

I would not rely on a single bearing suspension point (as in other answers) outdoors. Even with a high quality bearing you're likely to get movement in any substantial breeze, and if your balance isn't done just right it's likely to lean.

Here's what it might look like:

```
FRONT ELEVATION

            ╥ <-- floor flange against ceiling
            ║
            ║
            ║
            ║
      ▫═════╬═════▫ <-- cross, nipples and endcaps
            ║
            ║
      ▫═════╬═════▫ <-- cross, nipples and endcaps
            ║
            ║
            ║
            ║
            ╨ <-- floor flange against floor
```

If you size the vertical pipe in the center properly (with a nipple or custom cut at the store) you'll hit your VESA mount height with the crossbars. Put some holes in there at the proper width and use some plastic bushings to create a slight space between the pipes and the TV for clearance.

You can add fittings such as open tees where appropriate for cable management. If you want to get really fancy, use 90° or 45° elbows to bump the central section back so that the TV is centered between the floor flanges:

```
SIDE ELEVATION

            ╥
            ║                
            ║
            ╚═╗
           || ║
           ||:║
           || ║
           || ║
           ||:║
           || ║
            ╔═╝
            ║
            ║                
            ╨
```

As you do your planning, keep in mind that it's not really possible to build boxes (rectangles) with threaded pipe. You can fake it by grinding the threads off a non-critical joint, but you can't assemble it directly due to the logistics of the situation.

---

<sub>How did I build the diagrams? [Here's your huckleberry](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref). Scroll 2/3 down the page.</sub>

Comment: This sounds promising but over my head. Earnestly searched `cross tees protruding nipples` with unexpected results. (ツ) Basically you're saying to use the pipe flange and let the threads hold the weight and perform the rotation (with a limit). Could you explain more on the single bearing point and cross tees? Like I should use a 36" pipe with the flanges 18" deep in the cabinet/wall. Then use clamps above and below the center so it wont sway? https://www.amazon.com/EVIL-ENERGY-Exhaust-Preformed-Stainless/dp/B07YDHN42Q

Comment: You're overthinking it. I suggest a few minutes standing in the black iron pipe aisle with your thinking cap on. It's just like when you were a kid playing with Tinkertoys. See my updated answer for some clarity.

Comment: I like this answer.  It's simpler than either of my answers, and it's the only one where you can rig up the entire solution using off-the-shelf parts in a hardware superstore, so you know exactly how it's going to hang together.

Answer (score 6):

Look for a ***lazy susan bearing***.   There are various designs, sizes, weigh capacities, and most of them have a large opening for your cables.  You'll just have to rig your own end stops so they can't spin round and round.

[image]

or adapt an inherently rotating pole-style TV mount

[image]
[image]

Comment: The bottom left picture in the group of "lazy susan" bearings is actually a furniture/stool bearing and that's what you want to look at.  Actual Lazy Susan bearings have ridiculously low weight limits and don't handle lateral forces well at all but furniture bearings are made for that and also have large holes in the middle fore cabling.  Jay is right, they are all found by searching for "lazy susan", but check the weigh limits!

Comment: I was thinking of hanging it completely with no support below. I'll see if I can find any weight limits on an inverted lazy susan. Otherwise this option looks easy and I don't have to worry about my 5 year old trying to swing on it. Thanks everyone

Comment: Exactly @JPhi1618 there are some that don't even have ball bearings and struggle with 5 pounds and others that can easily handle hundreds of pounds.  You'd have to be hyper-precise in your search to hit exactly what you want without a bit of elimination.  Lazy Susan seems to be a good starting point.

Comment: Just stay away from *actual* lazy susan bearings that are designed as flat metal plates with the ball bearings sandwiched between them.  Other ones that are just *called* lazy susan bearings but support hundreds of pounds have the rings concentric and the balls in a plane between them.  Those can be used for hanging.  You could also look at automotive wheel bearings, they are CHEAP and at the whole skateboard market where it's normal to build your own wheels from scratch and the bearings are extremely strong.

Comment: I'm having trouble telling which lazy susan is which. Would this one be capable of hanging a few hundred pounds? https://www.amazon.com/industrial-turntable-plates-hardware-mechanism/dp/B081XXGV1Z

Comment: No, not that one.  You can see in the pictures of that one, the ball bearings are held in a channel from the top and bottom by two metal plates.   The balls only become engaged, and do their job, if the plates are squeezed together .... by placing something on top.  If you hang something, it pulls the plates apart and instead of engaging the balls, the weight then transfers to the rolled-over edge.  The bearing will not turn, and under heavy load it will rip open.

Comment: [Here](https://amazon.com/Heavy-Duty-Aluminum-Turntable-Single-Row-Bearings/dp/B071CPFM95/ref=sr_1_5) is an example of one that can be hung.  It does not even have a top and bottom, the rings are concentric and both can be engaged from either side.  The "commercial" one is probably best for your purpose.

Comment: [Something else](https://www.amazon.com/MAYASAF-Bearing-Assembly-Bonnevile-Century/dp/B07R9WQ8BV/ref=sr_1_8) that might work for you.  And for $32 it includes ABS sensors.  Maybe you could do something cute with that.

Comment: Having just fought with getting old wheel bearings out of my van, yeah, that would be a great idea! It would most certainly take the weight of a TV. "Cheap" is a relative, though, the aftermarket ones I got were cheap compared to the OEM, but compared to some black pipe, I'm not sure...

Comment: Ha! The ABS tone ring could be used for a powered solution for rotating the TV. Count the number of "blips" so you know when it's turned 180°! Of course, since it's powered, the kids can't spin it, either. One button press to "open" it and the next one "closes" it. The software knows the state and tells the hardware which way to spin.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way you could do it.  I like the answer from @isherwood, possibly better than my other answer about lazy susans because it's simpler.  You don't need ball bearings because you're not going to be spinning it round and round.    So if you're having trouble figuring out how to deal with threaded pipes and exactly what parts to use, consider this:

**Kee Clamps**

This is a system of clamps meant for building temporary railing systems, temporary structures, etc using tubular steel or aluminum.  You could easily adapt these for your needs.

Instead of threaded pipe, they use steel or aluminum tubes and they connect using set screws.  In your case you could adapt the set screws by drilling into the pipe for a more permanent set, or drilling through the pipe and using cotter pins.

There are many configurations you could devise but I think the simplest would just use two flanges (the leftmost part in the picture below) and a short length of pipe. The bottom flange would be screwed to the TV housing from underneath.  The upper flange would be resting loosely on the outer frame, separated by a ring of teflon. You don't need ball bearings.

These come in systems with different pipe diameters, I think you should use a 3/4 or 1 inch system.   For the pipe, the easiest thing would be to use electrical EMT or RMC because you can pick them up locally and they're easy to cut.

**Mounting the TV:**. You could also use a longer pipe, and extend it through the lower flange to the middle of the lower cabinet, where you would use a cross-pipe and a couple more flanges to connect your VESA mount.  That way, the TV is hanging directly from the pipe with its weight on the upper frame, and then the lower frame does not have to be structural, it only has to be strong enough to support its own weight and protect the TV from the elements.

[image]